# Could not load type 'Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.RewriterHttpModule'. - Godaddy Issue Cannot resolve

Tags: iis

After doing my bit of research and some looking around and researching I cannot find a definite answer nor can I get the URL rewriting to work on godaddy.

IIS 7. The home page works fine but when I go to myurl.com/controlpanel I get the following error

**Could not load type 'Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.RewriterHttpModule'.**

I have this file loaded on the Bin folder in the root.

Here is my web config file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- 
    Note: As an alternative to hand editing this file you can use the 
    web admin tool to configure settings for your application. Use
    the Website->Asp.Net Configuration option in Visual Studio.
    A full list of settings and comments can be found in 
    machine.config.comments usually located in 
    \Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\vx.x\Config 
-->
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    <section name="SubSonicService" type="SubSonic.SubSonicSection, SubSonic"  requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
        <section name="rewriter" requirePermission="false" type="Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.Configuration.RewriterConfigurationSectionHandler, Intelligencia.UrlRewriter"/>
    </configSections>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="sitelevel" value="2"/>
        <add key="sign" value="$"/>
        <add key="siteurl" value="http://myurl.com/"/>
        <add key="fromemail" value=""/>
        <add key="mailusername" value=""/>
        <add key="dateformat" value="ddmmyy"/>
        <add key="mailpassword" value=""/>
        <add key="mailserver" value=""/>
    </appSettings>
    <connectionStrings>
        <clear/>
  <add name="Icondice" connectionString="Data Source=serveraddress;Initial Catalog=db;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=db;Password=123"/>

        </connectionStrings>
    <SubSonicService defaultProvider="Icondice">
        <providers>
            <clear/>
            <!--CMS Provider-->
            <add name="Icondice" type="SubSonic.SqlDataProvider, SubSonic" connectionStringName="Icondice" spClassName="SPs" generatedNamespace="Icondice.DAL" stripTableText="Icondice.DAL_" fixPluralClassNames="true"/>
        </providers>
    </SubSonicService>
    <system.web>
        <pages enableEventValidation="false" enableViewStateMac="false" validateRequest="false">
            <tagMapping>
                <add tagType="System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompareValidator" mappedTagType="Sample.Web.UI.Compatibility.CompareValidator, Validators, Version=1.0.0.0"/>
                <add tagType="System.Web.UI.WebControls.CustomValidator" mappedTagType="Sample.Web.UI.Compatibility.CustomValidator, Validators, Version=1.0.0.0"/>
                <add tagType="System.Web.UI.WebControls.RangeValidator" mappedTagType="Sample.Web.UI.Compatibility.RangeValidator, Validators, Version=1.0.0.0"/>
                <add tagType="System.Web.UI.WebControls.RegularExpressionValidator" mappedTagType="Sample.Web.UI.Compatibility.RegularExpressionValidator, Validators, Version=1.0.0.0"/>
                <add tagType="System.Web.UI.WebControls.RequiredFieldValidator" mappedTagType="Sample.Web.UI.Compatibility.RequiredFieldValidator, Validators, Version=1.0.0.0"/>
                <add tagType="System.Web.UI.WebControls.ValidationSummary" mappedTagType="Sample.Web.UI.Compatibility.ValidationSummary, Validators, Version=1.0.0.0"/>
            </tagMapping>
            <controls>
                <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
                <add namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" tagPrefix="cc1"/>
                <add namespace="FredCK.FCKeditorV2" assembly="FredCK.FCKeditorV2" tagPrefix="FCKeditorV2"/>
                <add tagName="maincat" src="~/controls/maincat.ascx" tagPrefix="uc1"/>
                <add tagName="featuredsub" src="~/controls/featuredsub.ascx" tagPrefix="uc2"/>
                <add tagName="leftcategory" src="~/controls/leftcategory.ascx" tagPrefix="uc3"/>
                <add tagName="webnews" src="~/controls/webnews.ascx" tagPrefix="uc4"/>
                <add tagName="searchbox" src="~/controls/searchbox.ascx" tagPrefix="uc5"/>
                <add tagName="topMenu" src="~/controls/topMenu.ascx" tagPrefix="uc6"/>
                <add tagName="catbrand" src="~/controls/catbrand.ascx" tagPrefix="uc7"/>
                <add tagName="leftsubcat" src="~/controls/leftsubcat.ascx" tagPrefix="uc8"/>
                <add tagName="cartstatus" src="~/controls/cartstatus.ascx" tagPrefix="uc9"/>
                <add tagName="accountlinks" src="~/controls/accountlinks.ascx" tagPrefix="uc10"/>
                <add tagName="customertestimonials" src="~/controls/customertestimonials.ascx" tagPrefix="uc11"/>
                <add tagName="NewsLetter" src="~/controls/NewsLetter.ascx" tagPrefix="uc12"/>
                <add tagName="login" src="~/controls/login.ascx" tagPrefix="uc13"/>
                <add tagName="breadcrumbs" src="~/controls/breadcrumbs.ascx" tagPrefix="uc14"/>
                <add tagName="footerlist" src="~/controls/footerlist.ascx" tagPrefix="uc15"/>
                <add tagName="myaccountlink" src="~/controls/myaccountlink.ascx" tagPrefix="uc16"/>
                <add tagName="slider" src="~/controls/slider.ascx" tagPrefix="uc17"/>
                <add tagName="moremenu" src="~/controls/moremenu.ascx" tagPrefix="uc18"/>
                <add tagName="priceformula" src="~/controlpanel/controls/priceformula.ascx" tagPrefix="uc19"/>
                <add tagName="dealerprice" src="~/controlpanel/controls/dealerprice.ascx" tagPrefix="uc20"/>
                <add tagName="mymessages" src="~/controls/customermessages.ascx" tagPrefix="uc21"/>
                <add tagName="attachment" src="~/controlpanel/controls/attachment.ascx" tagPrefix="uc22"/>
                <add tagName="menurightschild" src="~/controlpanel/controls/menurightschild.ascx" tagPrefix="uc23"/>
                <add tagName="usermenurights" src="~/controlpanel/controls/usermenurights.ascx" tagPrefix="uc25"/>
            </controls>
        </pages>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
        <httpHandlers>
            <remove path="*.asmx" verb="*"/>
            <add path="*.asmx" verb="*" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false"/>
            <add path="*_AppService.axd" verb="*" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false"/>
            <add path="ScriptResource.axd" verb="GET,HEAD" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false"/>
            <!--<add path="*.aspx" verb="*" type="UrlRewriter" validate="false"/>-->
        </httpHandlers>
        <httpModules>
            <add name="UrlRewriter" type="Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.RewriterHttpModule, Intelligencia.UrlRewriter"/>
        </httpModules>
        <!-- 
            Set compilation debug="true" to insert debugging 
            symbols into the compiled page. Because this 
            affects performance, set this value to true only 
            during development.
        -->
        <compilation debug="false">
   <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
   </assemblies>
  </compilation>
        <!--
            The <authentication> section enables configuration 
            of the security authentication mode used by 
            ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
        -->
        <!--
            The <customErrors> section enables configuration 
            of what to do if/when an unhandled error occurs 
            during the execution of a request. Specifically, 
            it enables developers to configure html error pages 
            to be displayed in place of a error stack trace.

        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.htm">
            <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm" />
            <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm" />
        </customErrors>
        -->
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Strip Default.aspx Out">
          <match url="(.*)default.aspx" ignoreCase="false" />
          <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Canonical Host Name" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />

          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^myutl\.com$" />
          </conditions>

          <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.myurl.com/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
        <modules>
            <add name="UrlRewriter" type="Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.RewriterHttpModule"/>
            <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        </modules>
        <handlers>
            <!--<add name="*.aspx_*" path="*.aspx" verb="*" type="UrlRewriter" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv3.5"/>-->
            <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated"/>
            <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
            <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
            <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
    <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions.Design" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
    <rewriter>
        <!--Pages-->
        <rewrite url="~/store/(.+)-(.+).aspx" to="~/cms.aspx?cid=$2"/>
        <rewrite url="~/products/(.+)-(.+).aspx" to="~/product.aspx?prodid=$2"/>
        <rewrite url="~/news/(.+)-(.+).aspx" to="~/news.aspx?newsid=$2"/>
    </rewriter>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="MerchantAPIServiceEndPoint" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
            openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
            allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
            maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
            messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
            useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
              maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="WebHttpBinding_MerchantAPIService">
          <textMessageEncoding maxReadPoolSize="64" maxWritePoolSize="16"
              messageVersion="Soap12" writeEncoding="utf-8">
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          </textMessageEncoding>
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://merchantapi.apac.paywithpoli.com/MerchantAPIService.svc"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MerchantAPIServiceEndPoint"
          contract="MerchantAPIService" name="MerchantAPIServiceEndPoint" />

    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a good chance that there might be a server issue based on the info given. I recommend contacting support at http://x.co/WeHelp and requesting to have that function tested on the server you are using. Hope this helps.